# Sending a POST using HttpSendRequestA fails with ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I'm trying to post data to a test `.php` script using XAMPP on my local machine, but it always fails with `ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND`.  I check the server logs and no request was sent to Apache.  I can manually do it via a web browser and the php script runs as expected.

Here's the C++ code that doesn't work.  Can someone point out the problem?

```
static const char *accepttypes[]={ "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", NULL};
static const char headers[]="application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    
// open session
HINTERNET hsession;
if ((hsession=InternetOpen(_T("Whatever"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0)) != NULL) {
    HINTERNET hconnect;
    if ((hconnect=InternetConnect(hsession, _T("127.0.0.1"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0)) != NULL) {
        HINTERNET hpostreq;
        if ((hpostreq=HttpOpenRequestA(hconnect, "POST", "/mytest.php", NULL, NULL, accepttypes, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0)) != NULL) {
            BYTE *data=(BYTE*)"xyz=1234";
            DWORD datasize=8;
            if (HttpSendRequestA(hpostreq, headers, sizeof(headers), (LPVOID) data, datasize)) {
                ....
              
                // ^^^^^ That always fails with ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your call to `HttpSendRequestA()`:

- The value of `headers` needs to be changed from `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"` to `"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.
- `sizeof(headers)` needs to be changed to either `-1`, `sizeof(headers)-1`, or `strlen(headers)`.  You are expected to pass in either `-1` to let the function calculate the character length of the `headers` string, or you can pass in the actual character length. The string's null terminator is not to be included in that length.

Comment: It was the sizeof()-1 that was needed (I wondered about that).  The Content-Type was missing because when I changed from octet-stream back to to the urlencoded I had commented out,  I missed it on a copy/paste (ugh).  Thanks!!